# Store mongoose schema in database

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm pretty new to Mongoose and Nodejs.

I want to allow users to define a Mongoose Schema in my app, and save them in a database. Later they could then create documents following that Schema as well. Similar to a Headless CMS.

I've been able to create the schemas through an API request - but how would I go about saving the Schema for later use. Can I store a Mongoose Schema in a database?

All Schemas are created empty so all I need here is the name which is unique

```
    app.get(/create/:schemaName, (req, res) => {

      let Schema = mongoose.Schema;
      let myNewSchema = new Schema({
            schemaName: {
               type: 'String',
               default: ''
            },
            attributes: {
               type: Object,
               blackbox: true
            }
       });

       let model = mongoose.model(schemaName, myNewSchema)

       functionThatAddRoutesToModel(model)

    })
```

After I create the Schema, I add some API routes to that model

```
   function functionThatAddRoutesToModel(model){

     app.get(/exampleSchemaName/create, (req, res) => {
      // model.findOne etc etc
     })

     ...
   }
```

This all works, but if I turn of the node server, I loose all my Schemas and all the functionality goes away.

Would it be possible to store all the Schemas in a database or JSON format and then create all the Schemas when i boot up the server?

I also want to emphasize that I'm pretty new to this - so if you have alternative solutions to creating a headless cms like application - I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of letting users create schemas, why wouldn't you create a schema `mongoose.Schema({}, { strict: false })` with no attributes, and let users store documents with the fields they want.

> The strict option, (enabled by default), ensures that values passed to our model constructor that were not specified in our schema do not get saved to the db.

So, when you set it to false, this allows you to add attributes to your document.
**Example**:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({}, {strict: false});
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

let user = new User({ name: 'foo'});
user.save(); // _id: 5cabbdfc82f0532f2e66a962, name:"foo", __v:0

let user2 = new User({ age: 15});
user2.save(); // id: 5cabbdfc82f0532f2e66a963, age:15, __v:0
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

That's something I missed, will definitely add this. Could also then store the schemas in JSON format as a backup